# Does using Webpack for backend applications reduce performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, backend

I'm researching on Serverless applications using AWS Lambda and NodeJS.

I was looking into using Webpack to bundle all my NodeJS backend code into a single JavaScript file, and to use features like tree shaking.

For the way I understand Node works, *imports* (or *requires*) are resolved in runtime.

I'm afraid that bundling everything in a single file will affect my app's performance by always loading the entire JS file, instead of only loading the JS files as they are resolved during the code's execution. For a small application, the impact my be small, but as my app grows, the bundle will too.

I could create multiple bundles, one for each of my Lambda functions, but my question is: Is my concern valid?

In a mere NodeJS context, will bundling everything in a single file affect my performance, even by a small amount?

*Note: AWS Lambda **does** support ES5 so using Webpack just to transpile is not a factor in here.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think on the contrary it can improve the performance during the "warm up" of a Lambda.

Indeed when a Lambda is invoked for the first time or infrequently invoked, a container will be initialized and that is when `require()` will load the node modules. As `require()` is asynchronous and [can search for files in many places](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), having many files to load may slow down this invocation.

Note that once the "warm up" is done, the modules will already be loaded for next invocations and using a single file will not be an advantage anymore.

You can have some problems trying to use Webpack with some node modules that are not supposed to be executed in a browser (like ORMs for example) because they can contain some dynamic `require()` (using a variable as the parameter of `require()`).

---

To summarize, calling `require()` on a very big file should not be a big concern compared to calling `require()` on a lot of small files. But using Webpack can add complexity and if your lambda does not need to "warm up" very often, there is no difference.